# Integrating $\sec^2{x}$ by parts

Tags: integration, solution-verification

NB: yes, I know it is a common integral which equals $\tan{x}$, but if I brute force integration by parts, it must work, right? It is not working for me.

Firstly I have

$$\int \:\frac{1}{\cos^2x}dx=\int \:\:\frac{-\sin x}{-\sin x\cos^2x}\,dx$$

And after integration by parts with differentiating $\frac{1}{-\sin x}$ and integrating $\frac{-\sin x}{\cos^{2}x}$ I obtain **erroneously**

$$\frac{1}{\sin x\cos x}+\int \frac{1}{\sin^2x\cos x}$$

This did not seem to be close to $\tan{x}$, and sure enough the result came out to be $\frac{1}{\sin \left(x\right)\cos \left(x\right)}-\csc \left(x\right)+\ln \left|\tan \left(x\right)+\sec \left(x\right)\right|+C$

What went wrong?

Edit: I should've obtained $\frac{1}{\sin x\cos x}+\int \frac{1}{\sin^2x}$

Comment: Could you please add, how did you get the second line$$\frac{1}{\sin x\cos x}+\int \frac{dx}{\sin^2x\cos x}$$ ?

Comment: Then that must be where my mistake is. I'll add it in anyway

Answer (score 2):

For this again you need to know before hand that,

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sin^2x} = \int \csc^2 x dx = - \cot x +c$$

So finally,

$\begin{align}\frac{1}{\sin x\cos x} - \cot x +c &= \frac{1}{\sin x \cos x} - \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} +c \\&= \frac{1-\cos^2 x}{\sin x \cos x} + c\\& = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} +c \\&= \tan x+c \end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

I'll propose a different I.B.P. approach. If you know that $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$, then you can write
$$
\int \frac{1}{\cos^2(x)} \ dx =  \int \frac{\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} \ dx = \int \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} +1 \ dx = \int \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\sin(x) \ dx + x
$$
Taking $u = \sin(x)$ and $dv = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)}$ we get $du = \cos(x)$ and $v = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$, and hence
$$
\int \frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)} \ dx + x = \sin(x)\frac{1}{\cos(x)} - \int  \underbrace{\cos(x)\frac{1}{\cos(x)}}_{1} \ dx + x = \tan(x) -x + x + C =\boxed{ \tan(x) + C}
$$

---

To get that $\int \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)} \ dx = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ we use the substitution $ s = \cos(x) \implies ds = - \sin(x)$, so we get
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^2(x)} \ dx  = \int -\frac{1}{s^2} \ ds = \frac{1}{s} = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}
\end{align*}

Comment: Interesting and nice alternate method